# Assign a default variable if one is not inserted by user in C

Tags: c, variables, if-statement, scanf, strcpy

So I am working on a class assignment and I have the basic program down but I am trying to go above and beyond the assignment.  I have load from a predefined .dat file but I want to also give the user the option to define their own .dat file so here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //Loads Variables
    FILE *inputFile;
    char *firstName[15];
    char *lastName[15];
    char choice[15];
    printf("Welcome Friend File Importer\n");
    printf("What is the name of the file you want imported:\n");
    scanf("%s",&choice);
    printf("you entered %c\n",choice);
    if (choice == NULL)
    {   
        printf("Friends.dat Loaded By Default\n");
        choice = "friends.dat";
    }
    inputFile = fopen(choice, "r");  //Loads Input File
    //If there is an issue then let the user know
    if (inputFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("You got some issues... check to make sure the file exists.\n\n");
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    //Starts to print out the friends list
    printf("\nYour friends\n\n");
    fscanf(inputFile, "%s%s", firstName, lastName);
    while (!feof(inputFile))
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", firstName, lastName);
        fscanf(inputFile, "%s%s", firstName, lastName);
    }
    fclose(inputFile);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So I am wondering if the issue is because I am using scanf or is because I am trying to assign a variable inside of an if statement.  Please talk to me like I am five I have dyslexia and learn better by doing then by reading.

Comment: What's your problem?  You posted a bunch of code but not what the  issue is.  Also, `return -1` should be `return 1` on failure--the valid values to return are 0 to 255.

Comment: Sorry this is my error while trying to compile and link:         friends.c:23: error: incompatible types in assignment

Comment: Also thanks about -1 issue.

Comment: When you scanf a string(%s),don't include the ampersand(&) just before the variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *assign* to an array, you have to *copy* to it. In your case you should use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `strcpy` when you want to copy a string to another.

That is:

```
choice = "friends.dat";
```

has to change to

```
strcpy(choice ,"friends.dat");
```

And to print a string, you should use `%s` format specifier:

```
printf("you entered %s\n",choice);
```

instead of

```
printf("you entered %c\n",choice);
```

Answer (score 1):

`choice` is an array. You cannot assign to an array.

An array will never compare equal to `NULL`, since an array name in an expression will decay to the address of its first element.

To detect if no suitable input for `choice` was provided, it is easier to read the entire line first with `fgets()`, and then parse the line using `sscanf()`. Both `scanf()` and `sscanf()` return the number arguments were saved. So if `scanf("%s", choice)` returns 1, it means it succeeded in storing a string in choice. Otherwise, you can assume a failure occurred.

Comment: Yeah I just sent output through and I saw that

Comment: So I am guessing I have to verify that there was input and send it through that way?